# Filter items into the array within the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```js
const personData = {
  personList: [
    {

      personCodes: [
        {
          code: "001",
          desc: "Indian"
        }
      ]
    },
    
    {
     personCodes: [
        {
          code: "002",
          desc: "Spanish"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      personCodes: [
        {
          code: "001",
          desc: "Spanish"
        },
        {
          code: "002",
          desc: "Spanish1"
        },
        {
          code: "003",
          desc: "Spanish2"
        }
      ]
    },
    
    {
      personCodes: [
        {
          code: "001",
          desc: "Russian"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      personCodes: [
        {
          code: "001",
          desc: "Spanish"
        },
        {
          code: "002",
          desc: "Indian"
        },
        {
          code: "004",
          desc: "Japanina"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      personCodes: [
        {
          code: "001",
          desc: "Spanish"
        },
        {
          code: "004",
          desc: "Indian"
        },
        {
          code: "003",
          desc: "Japanina"
        }
      ]
    },
    
  ]
};

const personID = ["001","003"];

const result = personData.personList.filter(role => role.personCodes && role.personCodes.find(group => personID.includes(group.code)));

console.log(result);
```

Following code denotes the person Data with person List.
Each person List represents the code.
Once executing the code I am getting the 5 different kind of array which contains the code into the personID array.
I want the expected out like from the person Data 3rd and 6th object.
could someone look into it and modified the code ,I have already attached the required code.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `every()` on `personID` and then use `find()` inside that.

```js
const personData = { personList: [ { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Indian" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "002", desc: "Spanish" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Spanish" }, { code: "002", desc: "Spanish1" }, { code: "003", desc: "Spanish2" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Russian" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Spanish" }, { code: "002", desc: "Indian" }, { code: "004", desc: "Japanina" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Spanish" }, { code: "004", desc: "Indian" }, { code: "003", desc: "Japanina" } ] }, ] };

const personID = ["001","003"];

const result = personData.personList.filter(role => 
                 role.personCodes && personID.every(x => 
                    role.personCodes.find(a => x.includes(a.code))
               ));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another solution, basically you have to check with [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) if for **every** element `id` inside `personID` **some** `object` inside a `personCodes` array have a property `code` that equals `id`.

```js
const personData = { personList: [ { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Indian" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "002", desc: "Spanish" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Spanish" }, { code: "002", desc: "Spanish1" }, { code: "003", desc: "Spanish2" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Russian" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Spanish" }, { code: "002", desc: "Indian" }, { code: "004", desc: "Japanina" } ] }, { personCodes: [ { code: "001", desc: "Spanish" }, { code: "004", desc: "Indian" }, { code: "003", desc: "Japanina" } ] }, ] };
const personID = ["001", "003"];

const result = personData.personList.filter(role =>
{
    return Array.isArray(role.personCodes) &&
           personID.every(id => role.personCodes.some(p => p.code === id));
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```